# Looping to print array to multiple cells, "range of object _Global failed" error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am reading the names of multiple files in a directory. Each file has a title with five dashes in it. I would like to print these names to a sheet with the titles already separated by the dashes and put into individual cells.

For example, input:
marie-loves-orange-tabby-cats-100
shelby-hates-white-winged-moths-200

Output (where lines represent cells):
Marie | loves | orange | tabby | cats | 100
shelby | hates | white | winged | moths | 200

I hadn't seen a graceful way to print single dimension arrays to cells (although my way isn't terribly graceful either), and the examples I could find did not cycle through changing values. I tried one with simply A:E as the range, but this printed the same file name down the entirety of the cells. To fix this, I made a string with variable values to serve as the range, so that it would only print in those cells and then move down the sheet. A1:E1, then A2:E2, ... so on.

```vb
Dim vaArray   As Variant
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO     As Object
    Dim oFolder  As Object
    Dim oFiles     As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If oFiles.Count = 0 Then
        file_list = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
    Dim afterSplit() As String
    Dim rangeString As String
    Worksheets("filenames").Activate
    i = 1
    For Each oFile In oFiles
        afterSplit = Split(oFile.Name, "-", 5)
        rangeString = "A" + Str(i) + ":" + "E" + Str(i)
        Range(rangeString).Value = afterSplit
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

However, this throws a "Message 'Range' of object '_Global' failed" error without printing anything to the sheet. I appreciate any help with this.

Edit: Larger code snipped added for clarity.

Comment: You haven't `Set` `oFiles` variable. You have to set it to an object before you ask for the method. So this statement: `ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)` wont work as `oFiles` is not a files object yet. Think of it this way: if you buy a universal remote and bring it home, you have to set it to your TV before you start using it for you TV

Comment: @Zac I appreciate the advice but I did set oFiles, this is not the entire subroutine. I will update the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`Str`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function) documentation:

> When numbers are converted to strings, a leading space is always reserved for the sign of number. If number is positive, the returned string contains a leading space and the plus sign is implied.

If you `Debug.Print "A" + Str(i) + ":" + "E" + Str(i)`, you'll see the leading space and how this is an invalid range reference: `A 1:E 1` instead of `A1:E1`.

Use `&` to concatenate, and avoid `Str` entirely.

```
"A" & i & ":E" & i
```